# Questions on object declaring and a few image import statements for making a basic game

Tags: java, swing, object, jpanel, transparency

So my friend and I are making a very very basic game for fun, its going to be a top down (about 45 degree angle) where there is a lumberjack chopping down trees. Very basic and kinda lame I'm aware but we are just getting into semi-advanced java.

To start we decided we needed sprites for trees but we realized that no matter what it would be a rectangle with white pixels all around the tree, but that would cut out part of the background image. So we wanted to take every pixel that was white (whitespace/negative space), then make those pixels transparent. To do this we looked at a ton of codes and the one we saw the most was the code below, it worked but I don't quite understand it.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class simpleFrame extends JFrame {
   JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel() {
      ImageIcon originalIcon = new ImageIcon("image.png");
      ImageFilter filter = new RGBImageFilter() {
         int transparentColor = Color.white.getRGB() | 0xFF000000;
         public final int filterRGB(int x, int y, int rgb) {
            if ((rgb | 0xFF000000) == transparentColor) {
               return 0x00FFFFFF & rgb;
            } else {
               return rgb;
            }
         }
      };
      ImageProducer filteredImgProd = new FilteredImageSource(originalIcon.getImage().getSource(), filter);
      Image transparentImg = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(filteredImgProd);
      public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
         g.setColor(getBackground());
         g.fillRect(0, 0, getSize().width, getSize().height);
         g.drawImage(transparentImg, 140, 10, this);
      }
   };
   public simpleFrame() {
      super("Transparency Example");

      JPanel content = (JPanel)getContentPane();
      mainPanel.setBackground(Color.black);
      content.add("Center", mainPanel);
   }
   public static void main(String[] argv) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            simpleFrame c = new simpleFrame();
            c.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            c.setSize(700,700);
            c.setVisible(true);
         }
      });
   }
}
```

So what we don't exactly understand is why there are brackets after the declaration of the JPanel in the 6th line then I have no idea how the lines 6-16. Like in between the brackets, then the close bracket has a semi colon after it. I can't figure out how that works, every command line set aside but the structure of declaring the JPanel, JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel() {  };

Im trying to implement this so I can import an image to my JPanel class, then make all the negative space transparent, then paint it. I just cant seem to understand the structure of the program and how I could implement it into a class.

My code is the following:

```
public class Frame extends JPanel   {
    /*
     * This is the JPanel in which I want to add the transparent image to a JPanel
     * then add the JPanel object,"Frame", above in a JFrame declared in my
     * class above
     */
    public Frame()  {
        JPanel jp = new JPanel();
        jp.setSize(300,300);
        jp.setVisible(true);
        circle = new BufferedImage();           
        try {circle = ImageIO.read(new File("circle.PNG"));}
        catch (IOException ex) {}
    }
    public void paintComponents(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponents(g);
        g.drawImage(circle,0,0,300,300, null);
        g.drawRect(50, 50, 50, 50);
    }

}
```

It is only a test code to import an image, make it transparent, and then paint it on a JPanel. We are just trying to understand the best way to do this and the code that I found (the first code block) seems to do the job very well but we can't figure out the best way to implement it to our code.

Thanks in Advance,

Robbie and
Nick

Answer (score 0):

What the code in your example block with the `JPanel` is doing is declaring the JPanel's class right there--immediately--when it is instantiated. It's sort of coding shorthand. Doing that, they don't have to write a formal new, named class for the JPanel in a new .java file: the entire definition of the class is right there. If you look at it as a Java class definition, I'm sure it will make more sense.

If you take all the stuff out and put it in a formal Java class, inherited from JPanel, it should work. The formal name for what they're doing is called implementing an anonymous class (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html). I normally don't do it, because it makes the code much harder to read, but it's permitted.

HTH